# Problems compiling C core of igraph with Python 2.7.9 Anaconda 2.2.0 on Mac osx 10.10.2

Tags: python, igraph

I wonder if anyone has had a similar issue to this and found a solution? I am trying to install igraph for with Python 2.7.9 Anaconda 2.2.0 on Mac osx 10.10.2.

I managed to `brew install homebrew/science/igraph` OK but when I try to `pip install python-igraph` I get the following error:

```
   grep: /usr/lib/libiconv.la: No such file or directory
        sed: /usr/lib/libiconv.la: No such file or directory
        libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libiconv.la' is not a valid libtool archive
        make[3]: *** [libigraph.la] Error 1
        make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
        make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
        make: *** [all] Error 2

    Extracting igraph-0.7.1.tar.gz...
    Configuring igraph...
    Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.


    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/Users/Angela/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/x5/_j73bjsn10b5q1y_z904g3n40000gn/T/pip-build-nR59Ui/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x5/_j73bjsn10b5q1y_z904g3n40000gn/T/pip-e3LVvv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x5/_j73bjsn10b5q1y_z904g3n40000gn/T/pip-build-nR59Ui/python-igraph
```

I have tried `sudo pip` too with the same results. Any suggestion on what to try next would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution, I had to `brew install pkg-config` first, hope this helps anyone else with the same error

Comment: I have `pkg-config` already install, but get the same error as above.  Any other suggestions for me?

Comment: Found this email by Tamas [here](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2013-08/msg00057.html) where it is suggested to do `./configure --disable--graphml`. I did that and ran  `make` and got *igraph* to compile on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: This worked for me too !!! thank you so much, I was going out of my mind.