# Problems Installing python-igraph on Mac El Capitan

Tags: python, xcode, igraph, osx-elcapitan

I have a mac pro with 10.11.6 installed, and python 2.7.12 . I am trying to install python igraph but something is going wrong.

When I try to install the precompiled package i find here (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph) I get this warning

[image]

and then when I say install anyway, I get this:

[image]

On the other hand if I try  sudo pip install python-graph, the installation fails and I get this error

[image]

but my c libraries are correctly installed, and I use Version 8.1 every day to code in C++. Any idea on what I should do ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and I managed to solve it by following these steps:

Go to homebrew: [brew](https://brew.sh/) and install brew for Mac.

Then open the terminal and type the following:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew install cairo
brew install py2cairo
brew install igraph
sudo pip install python-igraph
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work, when I get to the last command, the terminal tells me that it couldn't download and compile the C-core of igraph. Any ideas why ?

Comment: After installing brew can you restart the pc and then try to run the commands ?

Comment: I have restarted the pc, and nothing changes. When I brew install igraph, the terminal tells me I already have it, then when I 'sudo pip install python-graph', i get the erro rregarding the C-core. If I try to import igraph, python doesn't find it. But I see the folder on my computer. I hope this doesn't seem overwhelming, and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I found a solution that for some reason works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589696/problems-compiling-c-core-of-igraph-with-python-2-7-9-anaconda-2-2-0-on-mac-osx